# What do goods do with money supply?

Tags: word-request

I am looking for a word that describes the relationship between money and goods and services in a way that shows money is supported by goods and services.

> Unless ____ with goods and services, additionally printed money accelerates inflation and leads to depreciation.

Back(ed)? Sustain(ed)? Supply(-ied)? What's the word?

Comment: I can't think of a single word that fits here. The closest I can get is **balanced** or **counterbalanced**.

Comment: Backed seems the natural choice.

Comment: The sentence is not grammatical in English.

Comment: @Lambie What exactly do you mean?

Comment: My question IS about something in particular. It's a classic word-request question. What a travesty, this moderation decision

Comment: I have edited and reopened the question for you. I think you should pay attention how to word your questions so that other people don't see them as off-topic.

Comment: I just read this question with @EddieKal's edit, and I gave it a +1. I can see how this would be difficult for a nonnative speaker to answer. I'm a native speaker and I'm finding it difficult to answer! (Ronald Sole's answer in a comment sounds very good to me, though.)

Comment: I would suggest “backed by” as did @mdewey. I think you could also say “tied to” or “anchored by”.

Comment: I mean that the money supply does not "do anything with goods".

Comment: @Lambie Actually, it was the other way around

Comment: Here's a question that actually makes sense: **What is the relationship between goods and the money supply?** Your question makes zero cents. [joke] Also, you completely changed your original question. How tricky. The title though is still nonsense.

Comment: And: Unless ____ with goods and services, additionally printed money accelerates inflation and leads to depreciation. is also poor English and poor economics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We usually use *back* in this sort of context. However the natural verb is *backed by* not *with*. I am not sure why but I suspect the idiom comes from the idea that the goods and services are figuratively standing behind the supply of printed money and hence supporting it. If you said *supported by* people would understand obviously. Supplied is definitely not the correct choice.

Historically paper currency was backed by precious metals. See for instance the [Wikipedia article on Gold Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_standard) which uses some variant of the word *back* 18 times when I looked just now.

Comment: What about 'anchored to'?

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev that would have the correct meaning but it is not, as far as I know, the word used in financial circles.

Comment: Can you kindly explain the question to me, as you understand it? Then, can you please tell me what you mean by back? In fact, can you explain the answer. It is a complete mystery to me.

Comment: @Lambie good point, I have linked to the relevant article in Wikipedia to provide more details and to support the use of back in this economic context.

Comment: You have explained nothing in relation to the sentence: "What do goods do with the money supply?" Please explain what the intended meaning is there. How could changing the verb make any difference? It's gibberish to begin with, both semantically and in terms of economics.